# Junit test case falling with Mockito and Spring MVC

Tags: java, junit, springmockito

I have a Controller Class which i am trying to test using mockito.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);
    private StaffService staffService;
    @Autowired
    public LoginController(StaffService staffService) {
        this.staffService = staffService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loginBean", new LoginBean());
        return "login";
    }}
```

My Test Class is show below:-

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginControllerTest {
    private static MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Mock
    private static LoginController loginController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loginController).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testShowLoginPage() throws Exception {
    loginController.showLoginPage(new ExtendedModelMap());
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(view().name("login"));
    }

}
```

But when i am running the test class i am getting the below error. Please help !

```
java.lang.AssertionError: View name expected:<login> but was:<>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ViewResultMatchers$2.match(ViewResultMatchers.java:69)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at com.expensecalculator.controller.test.LoginControllerTest.testShowLoginPage(LoginControllerTest.java:38)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you are mocking the controller that you are trying test. You should try this instead:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private static LoginController loginController;

    @Mock
    private StaffService staffService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        loginController = new LoginController(staffService);

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loginController).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();
     }

      @Test
      public void testShowLoginPage() throws Exception {
         mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(view().name("login"));
      }
}
```

Mockito's mock have all their method call replace by a default behavior, so when your standalone implementation reach the method it just return an empty string.